# automated task with selenium on a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have an application that is accessed by many users. It's a .net 4.0 C# web forms application, and they requested me to automate a task that they have to do almost daily. The task I should automate is to access a link outside my domain and fill it up with some info, log-in, and other stuff like dates.

So, after many researching and reading, I've managed to do it locally with Selenium. I have the entire process automated and I call it from a link inside my website. Locally it works like a charm.

Here's the code:

```cs
public void AutomateTask()
{
    var url = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4545/wd/hub");
    var capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
    var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");

    //do all the stuff I need to do

    driver.Close();
}
```

I start my server using this command:

```
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub -port 4545
```

The main problem is that I have to publish my website for the users and they should be able to use the automated process without having to start a selenium node on their machines or anything else. Locally I have a node running for each browser, is it possible for them to consume this webdrivers? I mean, users should not worry about installing or anything, they should just click the link and see their browsers acting till the task is over. When I click at the link on my application(from my local IIS) on another computer, a new window of the request browser is opened on server machine, not on the machine which clicked the link.

I've looking everywhere for a solution for this but none was found.

So:

1. I have a website that access a third website.
2. I need to automate this process.
3. Users must only click the link, wait the new browser window open, wait for some fields to be filled automatic and then fill the captcha and press "continue", then enjoy their browser working.

Is it possible with selenium? If not, which framework or how can I achieve this?

Let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to show the browser to the users you could just put a link on your webapp which runs selenium on the machine hosting your webapp.  That way you only need to have selenium installed and running on the webserver hosting your webapp and not all the end user machines.  If you do it this way you should probably use the HtmlUnitDriver because its headless and you really aren't going to be watching these selenium tests executing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is that I need the user to interact with the first screen where there's a captcha.